# Setting many fields in single id in django model

Tags: django-models

**I want to save model with single id with more then one item and quantity.**

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, verbose_name="item")
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can give a ID for every instances that are created on a cart and you can used that ID.